# Know which among the dependent keys caused the computed property change

Tags: node.js, ember.js, computed-properties

In Ember, is there a way to get which among the dependent keys caused a computed property to recalculate?

eg:

```
myProp: Ember.computed('dep1','dep2','dep3', function(){
    console.log('MyProp was recalculated due to a change in property :' <dep 1,2 or 3(get the value here)>);
    return ...;
}),
```

Kindly let me know if I should provide any additional details.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, thats not possible.

Long answer: You could save away all dependency keys and compare them on recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a component.js you can check didUpdateAttributes(options) where options contains the old and new values of updated attributes.

Comment: A note about Omar's answer: it's not exactly whether you "are" in a component, but whether these property changes affect component's lifecycle.

Example, if you inserted your component in an .hbs template like this

`{{blog-post title=title body=body}}`

You could observe within the `didUpdateAttributes` hook any changes in the  component's attributes `title` and `body`. But not any other property (computed or not) strictly internal to that component (not affecting it's lifecycle).

See

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/